# Is it possible to concatenate few videos together, setting their timings and displaying background image, if no video for the current frame?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an audio track, say, a few minutes long, as well as several short videos of several tens of seconds. For each of these videos I have a timing - the video should start at a certain second. The audio tracks of these videos are not needed.
The output video should last exactly as long as the audio lasts.
If at the moment there is no video to display, a picture should be displayed (as if the picture is on layer #1, and the rest of the videos are on layer #2).

Is it possible to complete this task using a command or a series of ffmpeg commands?

Comment: Sure, use the picture as base layer and overlay videos in successive overlay filters.

Comment: @Gyan Could you show an example as the answer?